# Mvc .net: Upload Multiple files in multiple fields via one http post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, file-upload, controller, http-post

I have model, with three properties:

1. `IEnumerable<File> photos`
2. `IEnumerable<File>Logos`
3. `File Video`

Can I post this model to a controller via on POST method? how can I configure to get files in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View:

```
<input type="file" name="Photos">
<input type="file" name="Photos">
<input type="file" name="Logos">
<input type="file" name="Logos">
<input type="file" name="Video">
```

You can populate uploaders with javascript.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(
       ViewModel model,
       IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Photos,
       IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Logos,
       HttpPostedFileBase Video )
    {
       ...
    }
```

We can also post uploaded files via a View Model, which is much more cleaner. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757604/file-upload-bound-to-the-viewmodel) for details.