# MVC File Upload with more than one property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There are links to explain [how to upload a file in MVC](http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp.net-mvc), but most of them only has a single input field (the file), and nothing else, which works with the following controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
...
```

1) What should I do if I have a ViewModel with multiple properties, and the file is one of the required fields?

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // ...other properties...

    // debug value: {string[1]} = "<filename-without-path>"
    public object File { get; set; }
}
```

When I debug, the value of `File` is `{string[1]}` with the file name, but without a path. I do not know what to do with that. I even tried to make the file of type `HttpPostedFileBase`, but that does not work.

2) The other problem is that it "forgets" the file name, e.g. when there are other validation errors that should be fixed.

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757604/file-upload-bound-to-the-viewmodel

Comment: The property value is `null` if I change the property type to `HttpPostedFileBase`. I must be missing something else.

Comment: Post your view markup.

Comment: It seems I was missing `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`. I posted an answer. (Not sure if MVC can pick this up automatically.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757754/371917

The form must have `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`, and then I can set the property type to `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Web:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ... modified from generated data ...

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

C#:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

2) I still do not know how to stop it from "forgetting" what the file was when there are other validation errors...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create property in your model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string ImagePath{ get; set; }
.....


}
```

In edit View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new 
                                       { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="ImageUpload">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="ImageUpload" id="ImageUpload" />
}
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var file = Request.Files["ImageUpload"];
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0){
            var uploadDir = "~/uploads"
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadDir), file.FileName);
            var imageUrl = Path.Combine(uploadDir, file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(imagePath);
            model.ImagePath= imageUrl;
        }

    }
}
```