# Uploading an image using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image to the database. My code is as follows:

I get the following error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

How can I get this to work ?

**VIEW**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.image, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.image, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", placeholder = "image" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.image)
        </div>
    </div>
```

**MODEL**

```
namespace MyPro.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Profile
    { 
         ...
         public byte[] image{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="")] Profile profile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            var pro= new Profile{ image = profile.image};
            db.Profile.Add(pro);

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("sucess");
    }
    return View(profile);
}
```

Database image:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload bound to the Viewmodel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757604/file-upload-bound-to-the-viewmodel)

Comment: This may be relevant:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string

I don't see any base64 encoding happening in your code.

Comment: could you please show the base64 encoded string you send to the server/try to save in db? Or do you actually not (want to) send the image as base64 encoded string? Then you should take a look at the .net streaming api. Either way, I think your problem is using byte[] in your model. Try using `HttpPostedFileBase` instead :) **edit**: as the other comments state.

Comment: Sorry, but i am a newbie. Can someone give me an example please.

Comment: If I make the image in the Model `HttpPostedFileBase `, then should I change the dataType for image in my Database as well ?

Comment: this may help you out, searching for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304617/html-helper-for-input-type-file

Comment: What does linq have to do with this?

Comment: @PeterBons Not everyone is a pro. Newbie's use the forum too. :)

Comment: The error I have mentioned in my post is fired even before the Controller is been executed. Why is this ?

Comment: As I already stated, because you try to store a data type inside a byte[] when the data is not at all a byte array. Use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() for the setter.

Comment: Ok. In my database (i have added a screenshot above), what should be the `data- type` for the image field ?

Comment: When I do this in MySql it is BLOB, your mileage may vary depending on your RDBMS.

Comment: @D.Foley I use MSSQL. I couldn't find anything called `BLOB`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518051/save-byte-array-in-sql-server

Shows how to store a blob in MSSQL. Be sure to use bound parameters when you do this.

Comment: Thank you. But now, i get another error `Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase' to 'byte[]' `. In my MSSQL DB the datatype I added was `varbinary(MAX)`, I also did generate my model, so the Datatype that was generated was `public byte[] image { get; set; }`. So I think there's a bit of a confusion between these 2 datatypes. How can I solve this ?